# Why numeric results in ghci and compiled code are different?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghci

I have a haskell code calculating defined integrals. When I run it from ghci I get:

```
tol = 1.0e-12 :: 11.83933789116509 :: 0.0
```

Where first column is tolerance, second column is an integral value and third column is an error.

But when I run absolutely same code, compiled with -O0 only I get:

```
tol = 1.0e-12 :: 11.839337891165126 :: 3.552713678800501e-14
```

Why is this happening?

P.S: code doesn't matter I guess. Just a lot of double arithmetic.

**UPD**: Here is the minimal example:

```
type R = Double
type F = R -> R

linearScale :: Fractional a => Int -> a -> a -> [a]
linearScale n x0 x1 = let h = x1 - x0 in
   map (\m -> x0 + h * fromIntegral m / fromIntegral n) [0 .. n]

triangulate :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]]
triangulate [] = []
triangulate (x:xs) = x : (triangulate xs')
    where xs' = map f xs
          f ys
            | head ys == 0 = drop 1 ys
            | otherwise = drop 1 $ zipWith (-) (map (* c) ys) x
            where c = (head x) / (head ys)

solve :: [[Double]] -> [Double] -> [Double]
solve ms bs = f (reverse ms) (reverse bs) []
    where f [] _ zs = zs
          f _ [] zs = zs
          f (x:xs) (y:ys) zs = f xs ys (z:zs)
            where z = (y - (sum $ zipWith (*) (tail x) zs)) / head x

gauss :: [[Double]] -> [Double] -> [Double]
gauss xs ys = solve ms bs
    where xs' = zipWith (\a b -> a ++ [b]) xs ys
          ts = triangulate xs'
          ms = map init ts
          bs = map last ts

integrateWithN :: Int -> F -> (Int -> R -> R -> R) -> R -> R -> R
integrateWithN n f mu a b = sum . zipWith (*) rs $ map f xs
    where xs = linearScale n a b
          mus = [mu s a b | s <- [0 .. n - 1]]
          xss = [map (^ i) xs | i <- [0 .. n - 1]]
          rs = gauss xss mus

main :: IO ()
main = print $ integrateWithN 60 f mu a b
    where
    f x = x
    intp k x = -0.39876 * exp(1.16315 * fromIntegral k) * (16 - 5 * x) ** (3/4)
    mu k a b = intp k b - intp k a
    a = 1.7
    b = 3.2
```

You'll get the different results running this code compiled with -O0 and from ghci.

**UPD:** ghc 7.10.3

My results:

[image: results]

Comment: probably a slight rewrite in the optimization yielding the usual float-point arithmetic issues (btw: a small example producing this type of issue would help a lot - as it is we can obviously only guess)

Comment: Er, _of course_ code does matter! Please post a minimal reproducible example. (Carsten is right, this is probably a floating-point associativity issue... but that hardly constitutes a proper answer.)

Comment: Quoting from the close reason: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. "  So, no a link to a github repository isn't enough. Moreover if you have 5k lines of code **you** should first try to obtain a minimal example that displays the problem.

Comment: Added example as minimum as possible in this situation.

Comment: Right, this looks _ok_ now. Still quite a lot of code; you have tried to boil it down _as much as possible_, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem, I get 11.530136779081658 as the result no matter how I compile and/or run your code (with GHC-7.10.2).

Comment: Sure. The discrepancy arises only in interpolation integration method, which depends on gauss method and I need hypergeometric function to calculate k-th moment. So, that's why I need all this code.

Comment: What's weirder is that [ideone](http://ideone.com/urDT55) and [codepad](http://codepad.org/SXSDw8V2) both fail to give proper results at all (with different errors!). It seems some call to a built-in maths function you do there is massively unstable... very strange.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Interesting, I get `11.580918029081658` (ghc 7.10.3, x86_64, os x)

Comment: @devmeow, it's not a question of dead code, but of things like: if you just don't call `triangulate` (set `ts = xs'`), will you still get a different result in ghci than in compiled code? Most likely you can do a whole lot of that sort of simplification.

Comment: Anyways my guess is that you are using a 32-bit GHC and this is just a classic 80-bit vs. 64-bit issue, though I don't understand @ThomasM.DuBuisson's result on x86_64.

Comment: @ReidBarton bit number doesn't seem to be the reason. GHC-7.10.2 gives me the 11.53 result both on x86_64 (Ubuntu14.04) and armv6l (Debian7.8 32-bit).

Comment: armv6l is not x87... so it doesn't have 80-bit doubles.

Comment: @reid-barton Ok. I've deleted hypergeometric function with saving the issue. Any other reductions results in same answers. Also, how to determine if ghc is 32-bit?

Comment: @reid-barton And ghci using the same ghc binary, isn't it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout the new version of code works on [ideone](https://ideone.com/6V3Fkz)

Comment: Run `ghc --info` and look at the lines "target arch" and "target word size".

Comment: @reid-barton, target arch: ArchX86_64, target word size: 8

Comment: ...and Ideone gives 5.783052853587137 as the result, which matches neither your 5.783052922423153 nor 5.7830528964079235, nor the correct result 3.675. — But really, these discrepancies look not so appalling anymore, this is the kind of error a badly-ordered floating-point summation may well give you. It seems to be the instability of your algorithm that blows up the deviations to anything between 1% and NaN. Still – I don't think GHC should reorder summations _at all_...

Comment: @devmeow, in that case, I don't know what's going on. Please file a bug (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket).

Comment: This is why floating numbers are terrible. See if using `Rational` helps.

Comment: @devmeow one way to ensure ghci is using the same ghc binary is just to run `ghc -i` to boot it into interactive mode.

Comment: One more hunch would be that it arises from compiled code using `sse` while interpreted code doesn't? But I think on 64 bit sse is used unconditionally, so it is only possible to toggle this on 32 bit arches.